# Use a page item in share component APEX ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, apex-code, ape

I computed a value using SQL and assigned it to a page item (P1_item) in page 1. I used this item in SQL query of a list of value in shared component (select col1 from table where col2=:P1_item). Then I assigned this list of value to another item in the same page 1. However, when I ran application, this item did not show any value.

I'm wondering if a local page item can be used in shared component for querying?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reference a page item in a shared component. However... there is no way to submit the page item to the shared component on refresh. So the value of your P1_ITEM needs to be set at rendering time. Also, the page item P1_ITEM needs to have the value when the select list is rendered. I suggest you run the page in debug mode to investigate into more detail. If this doesn't help, pls create a reproducible case on the emp/dept sample data set

Comment: Thanks for your comment. May I ask from the debug info, how can I know if value is submitted to the shared component or not?

Comment: That sentence about "submit the page item" is only for dynamic actions - in that case the value needs to be submitted to the session so it can be picked up when the list of values is refreshed. If the value is known at page rendering, well... then if the assignment of P1_ITEM happens before the rendering of the list of values it should be available. With the little amount of information available it is very hard to help you.